# System Memory (Internal Boot ROM) of STM32F446XX

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, bootloader, rom

The [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f446re.pdf) and [this article](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus/faq-stm32-boot-process/ta-p/49358) refer to an internal boot ROM that stores the bootloader on the STM32 MCU. The memory map (for the STM32F446RE) shows it to be at `0x1FFF0000 - 0x1FFF7A0F` and the "Boot Modes" section in the datasheet refers to it as system memory.

Where is this system memory/internal ROM physically on the chip? Is it simply a read-only portion of the Flash Memory (512Kb)? The MCU Block Diagram (Figure 3, Section 2 Description) seems to leave it out or at least doesn't show it as a distinct block.

Comment: it's provably not ROM per se

Comment: We might not know and ST might not tell us and different MCU may implement it differently. What would you do with the information, what problem will it solve if you knew how the system boot ROM is stored?

Comment: According to the introductory text of the article, it is flash memory. To find out whether it is part of the 512 KiB, you can try to write an application that fills all the space (the linker will warn you) or look into the linker script.